# Fail to install enterprise in house distribution App on iOS Device first time

Tags: ios, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have an app that can be downloaded through a S3 Bucket using Enterprise Distribution and It is failing first time and shows loading but when i install certificates manually using configuration utility by connecting device to computer, the same website link start working. I am using Jenkins for creating build.

The certificates not getting install automatically, I am using the manifest as per apple standard. my manifest file content is following :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN"     "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>items</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>assets</key>
        <array>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>software-package</string>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>https://dev-ios-builds.mycompany.com/AppName-1.0-56-2016-06-07.66.ipa</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>display-image</string>
                <key>needs-shine</key>
                <true/>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>https://dev-ios-builds.mycompany.com/images/Icon.png</string>
            </dict>
            <dict>
                <key>kind</key>
                <string>full-size-image</string>
                <key>needs-shine</key>
                <true/>
                <key>url</key>
                <string>https://dev-ios-builds.mycompany.com/images/iTunesArtwork.png</string>
            </dict> 
        </array>
        <key>metadata</key>
        <dict>
            <key>bundle-identifier</key>
            <string>com.companyname.appname.dev</string>
            <key>bundle-version</key>
            <string>1.0</string>
            <key>kind</key>
            <string>software</string>
            <key>title</key>
            <string>AppName Dev</string>
        </dict>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [download-inhouse-app-from-another-app-programmatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37156632/download-inhouse-app-from-another-app-programmatically/37157308#37157308)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out the problem by checking device logs it says embedded provisioning  not found.

I just un-packaged the .ipa file which is created by using Jenkins and compared it with .ipa created by using Xcode. I got the difference that jenkins not embedding the provisioning profile correctly.

I had done a mistake by giving folder path for provisioning profile in jenkins job, just updated this by particular provisioning file path.

[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue with development builds. My Jenkins built and signed the binary, then uploaded to HockeyApp for distribution, but somehow people with new devices could not install the builds, even though their devices were in the provisioning profile. I discovered that Jenkins was using a custom development provisioning profile instead of the team provisioning profile managed by Xcode. The symptoms were exactly as you describe it, when I manually installed that custom profile on their devices they were able to install the app.

What solved it for me was to update Jenkins job to use the team provisioning profile instead of a custom one. Perhaps you should check what your Jenkins uses exactly to sign the app?